# How to change default language in Microsoft Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I just downloaded Visual C++ off the Internet and the application is in French. Any way to switch the language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you downloaded the Express edition, no, not without downloading the Express edition in whatever other language you want.

Comment: Yes, sad thing I learned when I tried to get the English language for my roommate's Visual C# Express install. I have a feeling Microsoft isn't trying too hard since it's free.

Comment: Guess your right... just about to install an english version - theres no uninstall program either

Answer (score 1):

`Tools -> Options -> Environment -> International Settings -> Language`

Comment: Hmm only langue it gave the option for was french or Identique au Microsoft Windows