# Where to download Visual C++ for Windows XP

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Questions all in the title. I've been trying for the past hour to get it. The first time, it came in French ([How to change default language in Microsoft Visual C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660618/how-to-change-default-language-in-microsoft-visual-c)). I can't seem to find one that doesn't come with a free toolbar and so many viruses that my Computer would explode. Can *anyone* help?

EDIT: @log0 has got the answer and rightly states in the comments that this kind of question is suitable for SO as defined in the FAQ. Can we reopen it (and possibly remove downvotes)? If you have downvoted, please can you explain why in the comments so I can rectify this question?

Comment: [Express Editions](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products) are available from Microsoft. Other editions you purchase.

Comment: The question addresses "software tools commonly used by programmers" as described by the FAQ. It is reasonably scoped and similar to many questions on SO concerning where to download or which tool to use. It should probably not be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Express Editions with SP1, from Microsoft download center:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14597

Comment: you seem to have overlooked the fact that that download doesn't support windows xp

Comment: @inmulsion indeed, but I corrected the link few seconds after my first answer. This one link to VS express 2008, supported by any version of windows XP.

Comment: vcsetup.exe should be the c++ version

Comment: Link down, but archived on [wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20121129231405/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14597), and the net installer still works.