# How to change default language in Microsoft Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have downloaded Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express edition and it turns out to be a french version. How can I change the default language of the edition to english?

However I read the similar post 
[How to change default language in Microsoft Visual C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660618/how-to-change-default-language-in-microsoft-visual-c)

but not able to find the path mentioned ..
Tools -> Options -> Environment -> International Settings -> Language (in french 
Outils -> Options - > Environnement - > Paramètres internationales - > Langue )

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have multiple spoken languages inside of Visual Studio you must install multiple languages of Visual Studio. For each language version of Visual Studio you installed you will get another option in the Interantional Settings menu.

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246590.aspx) for more info.

Once the trial installation is finished you are able to switch languages in

> Tools -> Options... -> Environment -> International Settings

You can even uninstall the german version through appwiz.cpl. Look for Visual Studio components with de or DEU endings.

It seems that the license is language independent.